# 'Series' object has no attribute 'tax_code'

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe with 2 columns user_id and tax_code and many rows. I imported this library https://pypi.org/project/python-codicefiscale/ and i need to verify if a tax_code is valid or not.

i tried to define this function that doesnt give me back errors.

```
def valid():
    from codicefiscale import codicefiscale
    if df.tax_code.codicefiscale.is_valid():
        return "It's Valid"
    else:
        return "Not Valid"
```

i did this to create a new column and apply my function:

df["Is Valid"]=df.apply(valid)

i have this error displayed:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'tax_code'
```

How can i solve it? tax_code is the name of my 2nd column

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly i dont know if this causes any problems but avoid importing
   inside your code, to my best of knowledge importing always goes in
   the beginning
2. Secondly i think your error is caused on the if statement. There you
   try to search for the 'tax_code' as it is a Dataframe attribute. Try
   using it inside [''] as you would normally do

Comment: def valid(row):
    if df["tax_code"].codicefiscale.is_valid():
        return "It's Valid"
    else:
        return "Not Valid"
i dont have any problem on the function and i did as you said importing library first.

df["Is Valid"]=df.apply(valid)

now when im executing this i have this error:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'codicefiscale'

Comment: you are trying to "execute" your method  ".codicefiscale.is_valid()" as an attribute. In the documentation you sent your method takes a string as a parameter. Try using something like codicefiscale.is_valid(df['tax_code'])

Comment: i tried to put in the function df["tax_code"] and executing but same problem AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'codicefiscale'